# Magento 1.x installation guide

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I want to work on magento 1.x for one of my client. But i am not finding any code base or downloadable link any where for magento 1.x. If any one know where to download and Installation guide its appreciable.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing.html

Comment: i's worth noting support for Magento 1.X is stopping (or has stopped - can't remember), and it's worth it more nowadays to learn Magento 2

Comment: @Marius thanks for link. i want to download repo. I am not finding repo.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs true but thing is i cant upgrade. I want to build on existing version for my client.

Comment: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download Not sure if you can get the latest 1.9 version from here, but get what you can and you can upgrade to 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

> you can download magento from [magento.com](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) Under **Release Archive** tab find **ver 1.9.x** from here you can select your magento version and Select your format and download.
>
> [Magento 1.x Installation Tutorial](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento-1/manual-installation/)

Comment: Got it thank you so much @chander shekhar

Comment: cheers.........

Answer (score 0):

You can also download magento from mageplaza website without login below are the link

[Download Magento 1.9.3.6](https://www.mageplaza.com/download-magento/#download-Magento%201%20from%20OpenMage)

Answer (score 0):

- Go to https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and click on **Release Archive** tab.
- Find **ver 1.9.x** section on this page and select the format from the drop-down under ver 1.9.3.6 sub-section.
- Finally click on Download button.

[image: ver 1.9.x section]

**Alternate:** If you are unable to find the section on the page, you can find the latest version https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/archive/1.9.3.6.zip

Comment: thank u found. I am able to install 1.7 too.

Comment: Can you upvote if it helped?

Comment: sorry i recently created account i don't have reputation points to upvote.